# ng-repeat isn't iterating over array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

**Simplified HTML:**

```
<div ng-repeat="transfer in transfers">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th translate>Description {{ transfer.entries | json }}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="entry in transfer.entries">
                <td>{{ entry.description }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Simplified JS:**

```
      $scope.transfers = transfers;
      $scope.total = transfers.meta.count;

      for (var i = 0, j = $scope.transfers.length;
           i < j;
           i++) {

        if (!$scope.transfers[i].hasOwnProperty('entries')) {
          $scope.transfers[i]['entries'] = [];
        }

        $scope.transfers[i]['entries'].push({
          description: 'A description'
        });
      }
```

The first `{{ transfer.entries }}` (the one that is to the right of "Description") shows the correct value for `transfers[i].entries`, something like `[{"description":"A description"}]`, but for some reason the ng-repeat is not iterating over that array.

To recapitulate:

- They are on the same scope.
- The regular binding is working properly.
- The ng-repeat seems to not be correctly capturing the transfer.entries value.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you used AngularJS Batarang on Chrome to inspect the model?

Comment: No, just plain Firefox Dev Tools/Console/console.log, visual confirmation that the first binding is working properly, which is what is having me going crazy.

Comment: I will check it now and let you know, but in the meantime, can you point me out to possible issues?

Comment: Possibly a dumb question, but is transfer.entries actually an object?

If it's outputting all that text as a string, that implies it's just a JSON looking string, and not actually a parsed json object.

Comment: @TheChafing There are no dumb questions :) Is outputing the string formatted object since I filtered it with `| json`

Comment: It seems to works well here: http://codepen.io/jlowcs/pen/LEXgPR

Comment: It seems to :( I will continue to check if something else is interfering. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks all for your help. Finally, I was able to find the issue. It is due the fact that I was using `dir-paginate` directive to do the repeating, not ng-repeat itself. Once I fall back to ng-repeat it worked fine, so I'm presuming is a scope issue (due isolated scope).

Answer (score 0):

Well, It seems that I crashed into a bug.

https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/issues/92

The hard part was to determinate that was the directive the one with the issue.

Thanks all for your time.